# how to group_by one variable and count based on another variable?

Tags: r, group-by

Is it possible to use group_by to group one variable and count the target variable based on another variable?
For example,

| x1 | x2 | x3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 0 |
| B | 2 | 1 |
| C | 3 | 0 |
| B | 1 | 1 |
| A | 1 | 1 |

I want to count 0 and 1 of x3 with grouped x1

| x1 | x3=0 | x3=1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 |
| B | 0 | 2 |
| C | 1 | 0 |

Is it possible to use group_by and add something to summarize? I tried group_by both x1 and x3, but that gives x3 as the second column which is not what we are looking for.

If it's not possible to just use group_by, I was thinking we could group_by both x1 and x3, then split by x3 and cbind them, but the two dataframes after split have different lengths of rows, and there's no cbind_fill. What should I do to cbind them and fill the extra blanks?

Answer (score 2):

using the data.table package:

```
library(data.table)
dat <- as.data.table(dataset)
dat[, x3:= paste0("x3=", x3)]
result <- dcast(dat, x1~x3, value.var = "x3", fun.aggregate = length)
```

Comment: nice - you can skip the as.data.table here, just feed `setDT(dat)` to dcast; also I think best to wrap this in `setnames`. Like:  `setnames(
  x =dcast(setDT(dat), x1~x3,length),
  new=c("x1", paste0("x3=",unique(dat$x3)))
)`

Comment: My advice would be to keep the operations separated for a better readability. But that's up to you

Comment: You should at least add the name change to your response, even if in different line, so that you fully answer the OP's question (i.e. matching their desired output)

Comment: Ok I didn't get his was your point. done

Answer (score 0):

A `tidyverse` approach to achieve your desired result using `dplyr::count` + `tidyr::pivot_wider`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  count(x1, x3) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "x3", values_from = "n", names_prefix = "x3=", values_fill = 0)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   x1    `x3=0` `x3=1`
#>   <chr>  <int>  <int>
#> 1 A          1      1
#> 2 B          0      2
#> 3 C          1      0
```

**DATA**

```
df <- data.frame(
                x1 = c("A", "B", "C", "B", "A"),
                x2 = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L),
                x3 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Here is an example:

```
dat = read.table(text = "x1     x2  x3
 A  1   0
 B  2   1
 C  3   0
 B  1   1
 A  1   1", header = TRUE)

dat %>% group_by(x1) %>% 
        count(x3) %>% 
        pivot_wider(names_from = x3,
                    names_glue = "x3 = {x3}", 
                    values_from = n) %>% 
        replace(is.na(.),0)

# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   x1 [3]
# x1    `x3 = 0` `x3 = 1`
#  <chr>     <int>     <int>
#1 A             1         1
#2 B             0         2
#3 C             1         0
```